# Is it possible to create own Qt annotations?

Tags: c++, qt, annotations

Is it possible to create own annoations in Qt like in Java?

```
@interface Test {
    boolean value();
}
```

Edit: 
Okay, to clairify why i wanted to do this, i will strike out a bit and try explain it. Maybe its not even possible.

I want to create classes which got some properties. In a GUI Application i want to use this classes and generate the GUI(QML) dynamically with the use of `QMetaObject`.

To restrict the user inputs i thought to add annoations like "minValue" and "maxValue"

But what i've found out now is, that there would be no possibility to read out annoations with the `QMetaObject`, because they doenst exists like @mohabouje mentioned. There is the `Q_CLASSINFO` macro, but this only describes a class not a property.

Is there any way to do this? Or can someone give me some hints?

Comment: This article helped me a lot.
https://ruedigergad.com/2011/11/13/exchange-data-and-objects-between-c-and-qml-and-vice-versa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For methods there is a possibility to use the tag property, to add annotations

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#tag

Copied from the documenation:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
// define the tag text as empty, so the compiler doesn't see it
#  define MY_CUSTOM_TAG
#endif
...
private slots:
    MY_CUSTOM_TAG void testFunc();
```

-

```
MainWindow win;
win.show();

int functionIndex = win.metaObject()->indexOfSlot("testFunc()");
QMetaMethod mm = win.metaObject()->method(functionIndex);
qDebug() << mm.tag(); // prints MY_CUSTOM_TAG
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do it, this is C++, not Java. by the way an alternative to do it is using  #defines, it can give you an approximate solution:

```
#define INTERFACE virtual
#define DECL_INTERFACE = 0
#define OVERRIDE override
#define IMPLEMENTS : public
```

Then inside your interface class you can do:

```
class InterfaceClass {
   INTERFACE std::string compute() DECL_INTERFACE;
   INTERFACE void something_else() DECL_INTERFACE;
}
```

And in your sub class:

```
class Subclass IMPLEMENTS InterfaceClass {
   std::string compute() OVERRIDE {
     ....
   }

   void something_else() OVERRIDE {}
}
```